# Session still keep value after tomcat down

Tags: php, apache

I am using XAMPP app for my server.
in my page: I write code for update session value as below

```
<?php
session_start();
$start = isset($_SESSION['start']) ? $_SESSION['start'] : 0; 
$_SESSION['start'] = $start + $num;
?>
```

I run server in long time, after that I shutdown XAMPP with apache service
after I restart apache again, I see that session value still keep ?

Comment: if you want to delete all session data, use `session_destroy()`. if you want to unset a specific field, use e.g. `unset($_SESSION['start']`

Comment: It seems your garbace collector is not doing it's job.

Comment: May be your Apache server storing PHP sessions in Memcached.

Comment: As I think, after server down, all session is destroy.